# Adding rows from JTable to another JTable

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtable

I'm onto the last part of my project, this is one of the last problems I'm having with it. This part is for editing a booking, i.e changing the rooms booked for a particular booking.
I have 2 JTables, one with available rooms and another with rooms already booked for that booking. Both have separate DefaultTable models and 2D Object arrays. 
I have an add and a remove button between the two tables, which swaps over the row you have selected.

The problem  is that it works fine for the first add/remove, but I think I'm not refreshing the 2D array. On the second attempt to add another row the model is still referring to the original 2D array, as I don't remove the row from the 2D array so it gives me the wrong row data.

Is there an easier way of addressing this issue using a JTable/model method, rather than creating a temporary 2D object array to exclude the selected row?

Example code below to show the ActionPerformed code.

```
if(e.getSource().equals(addRow)){ 
        System.out.println(tableLeft.getSelectedRow());
        if(tableLeft.getSelectedRow() == -1){  //if no row selected

        }
        else{
            model.insertRow(tableRight.getRowCount(),array2dLeft[tableLeft.getSelectedRow()]);
            modelLeft.removeRow(tableLeft.getSelectedRow());
            modelLeft.fireTableRowsDeleted(tableLeft.getSelectedRow(),tableLeft.getSelectedRow());
            txtTotalCost.setText("€" + getTotalCost());
        }   
    }
    if(e.getSource().equals(removeRow)){
        if(tableRight.getSelectedRow() == -1){  //if no row selected                
        }
        else{
            modelLeft.insertRow(tableLeft.getRowCount(),array2dLeft[tableRight.getSelectedRow()]);
            model.removeRow(tableRight.getSelectedRow());
            txtTotalCost.setText("€" + getTotalCost());
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I think I'm not refreshing the 2D array.

You should not be accessing the 2D Array. The array should only be used to initially load data into the table model. Then you can set the Array variable to null so you are not tempting to use it again.

After that all updates should be done directly on the TableModel, using the `addRow()` and `removeRow()` methods of the `DefaultTableModel`.

You will also need to use the `getValueAt(...)` method of the TableModel to get the data from the model so you can create a Vector (or Array) of the row data and use the addRow() method with the data.

Comment: Ah, works beautifully now. I'll give you some credit in my references, thanks!